# In Python, how do you call a function that has had arguments passed to it from a third location

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter, parameter-passing

So I am writing a tkinter GUI program that passes arguments to three functions in a separate script. Those three functions are then called in said script's main function and instantiated as variables so that the return values of those functions can be referenced.

(As I am not at liberty to share the code I will make an illustration of what I am trying to do)

This shows how the GUI code passes values to functions in another script

```
# GUI code


function1(e,f,g,h)
function2(i,j)
function3(j,k)
```

And this is the code that containing the functions that values are getting passed to:

```
def function1(w,x,y,z):
    return w,x,y,z

def function2(x,y):
    # function code
    return a, b, c

def function3(y,z):
    # function code
     return a, b, c

def main():
    1 = function1()
    2 = function2()
    3 = function3()
    #other code where the return values of each function is called

main()
```

My question is how do I instantiate the three functions as variables in main without passing additional arguments to them? the reason I am trying to do this is because every time I import my GUI into the other script, the other script simply returns my GUI, so it seems that any interaction can only go one way.

Comment: Your question and your code does not make any sense.

Comment: This isn't how function calls work. It sounds like you have several fundamental misunderstandings of how function calls work, how `import` works, and likely how GUI programming works, but we don't have enough information to address those misunderstandings in detail.

Comment: _"As I am not at liberty to share the code"_ - we don't need your actual code. What we need is code created specifically for this question that adequately replicates the problem you are trying to solve.  The pseudocode you wrote isn't runnable and your description is a bit vague, so it's difficult to know exactly what problem you're having.

Comment: As others said, your question isn't very clear, but what you're probably looking for is `lambda`.